# How to create a link to Dropbox folder?

Tags: windows, dropbox, junction

I've moved *My Documents* to another drive. Windows still shows *My Documents* in `C:\Users\Username\My Documents` and links this to `D:\...`

Can I do the same with my Dropbox folder? I want a virtual "Dropxbox" folder insider `C:\Users\Username\`, that links to the Dropbox on drive D. It should be displayed as a folder, not a link, as a .lnk file would.

This seems to be possible for special folders by using the `FolderName.{CSLID}` syntax, e.g. for "Network locations". Is there a similar way for Dropbox?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a symbolic link to the `DropBox` folder.

In the `Command Line` type: `mklink /J D:\DropboxFolder C:\OtherFolder`